# How to embedd Camunda engine and admin/tasklist/cockpit with my own Spring Security webapp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, camunda

1) I have successfully integrated "embedded-spring-rest" example Camunda project with Spring Security. Now I am struggling how to integrate Camunda Tasklist/Cockpit/Admin modules with the former ("embedded-spring-rest" + Spring security). I can't find any examples.

2) I am also trying to bypass Camunda user authentication in order to use user context (login) from Spring Security.

Has somebody achieved to do something similar in 1) or 2) or are there any related examples?

Answer (score 2):

I am not completly sure what you exactly want to package - and how. But the Spring Boot Starter Community Extension (https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter) could give some guidance. It starts the Camunda Webapp via Webjar as part of Spring Boot.

Cheers
Bernd

Comment: Hey Bernd, thank you for the answer, I will check the link :) To be more specific if others are wondering, I want to add Camunda webapps (tasklist for example) to exiting Spring webapp (with Spring Security enabled), which includes embedded Spring Engine with REST API.

Comment: You might join the discussion in https://forum.camunda.org/t/exchange-rest-api-the-webapp-is-using/1463/2,  I am trying to achieve the same, but by moving the complete rest api to the existing application and using a standalone camunda-webapp that just uses the api ... this will not require the webapp/ui to be embedded into  the application-war

Comment: Another idea would be to use the spring-starter Bernd mentioned, integrate the complete existing application and then build the springboot archive as a war file ... there is an example in the github project that shows how its done. Anyway: if you are succesful, please share, its exactly what I need.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion link, it will surely prove useful. I will inform of any next successful step on the forum.

Comment: Okay, I have achieved my goal by adding my own REST service to the geoserver/src/web/app project. Maybe it's a bit extreme, but it serves my goals ;) Mainly it required adding the external (my own) REST service and related classed to the Geoserver web.xml and applicationContext.xml files. When Geoserver is started this service coexits with Geoserver and is accessed in its path (Geoserver/rest2).